# Set variable equal to two if statements in one line

Tags: python, if-statement

I need the variable to work like this:

```
fppg_multiplier = 2 if row['Roster Position']
== 'MVP' else 1.5 if row['Roster Position'] == 'STAR' else 1
```

How can I do this in one line?

```
@SitesRegistry.register_csv_importer
class DraftKingsCaptainModeCSVImporter(DraftKingsCSVImporter):  # pragma: nocover
        site = Site.DRAFTKINGS_CAPTAIN_MODE

        def _row_to_player(self, row):
            try:
                fppg_multiplier = 2 if row['Roster Position'] == 'MVP' else 1
                fppg_multiplier = 1.5 if row['Roster Position'] == 'STAR' else 1
                name = row['Name'].split()
                player = Player(
                    row['ID'],
                    name[0],
                    name[1] if len(name) > 1 else '',
                    row['Roster Position'].split('/'),
                    row['TeamAbbrev'],
                    float(row['Salary']),
                    float(row['AvgPointsPerGame']) * fppg_multiplier,
                    game_info=self._parse_game_info(row),
                    **self.get_player_extra(row)
                )
            except KeyError:
                raise LineupOptimizerIncorrectCSV
            return player
```

Comment: What output do you get from running this? Do you get an error?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why it has to be in one line? Typically when you strive to make things are short as possible you lose a lot of the pythonic characteristics of the language and it becomes much less readable.

Comment: No error fppg is just equal to 1.5

Comment: It looks like the first code block you wrote should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me if I put it all on one line:

```
>>> row = {}
>>> row['Roster Position'] = 'MVP'
>>> fppg_multiplier = 2 if row['Roster Position'] == 'MVP' else 1.5 if row['Roster Position'] == 'STAR' else 1
>>> fppg_multiplier
2
>>> row['Roster Position'] = 'STAR'
>>> fppg_multiplier = 2 if row['Roster Position'] == 'MVP' else 1.5 if row['Roster Position'] == 'STAR' else 1
>>> fppg_multiplier
1.5
>>> row['Roster Position'] = 'XXX'
>>> fppg_multiplier = 2 if row['Roster Position'] == 'MVP' else 1.5 if row['Roster Position'] == 'STAR' else 1
>>> fppg_multiplier
1
```

Answer (score 1):

If writing in a single line is crucial, you can write a custom function like:

```
def getval(x):
    if x=='MVP':
        return(2)
    elif x=='STAR':
        return(1.5)
    else:
        return(1)
```

And then simply call the function whenever needed. As an example:

```
fppg_multipler = getval(row['Roster Position'])
```